# Cube root of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

I'm reading [Linear Algebra Done Right](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PULZWPC) by Sheldon Axler. In Chapter $1$, Exercise $A$, #2, it states:

Show that  $(-1 + \sqrt{3i})/2$ is a cube root of $1$.

The solution on linearalgebras.com shows the following solution [here, at number 2.](http://linearalgebras.com/1a.html)

It states that $(-1 + \sqrt{3i})/2$ squared is $(-1 - \sqrt{3i})/2$. I can understand the rest of the solution but I don't know how they got past the first step. I even squared the above value in an [on-line calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/factor-calculator/%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(1-sqrt%5Cleft(3i%5Cright)%5Cright)%7D%7B2%7D%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(1-sqrt%5Cleft(3i%5Cright)%5Cright)%7D%7B2%7D%20) and it gave me a different value. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The symbol $\sqrt{~}$ is meaningless for a complex number: it denotes the positive square root of a positive real number.

Comment: Most certainly it is $\sqrt{3}\,i$, rather than $\sqrt{3i}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $i$ should not be inside the square root.

It should be $$\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt3 \,i}{2}\right)^{\!2}=\frac{-1-\sqrt3 \,i}{2}$$

rather than

$$\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{3 i}}{2}\right)^{\!2}=\frac{-1-\sqrt{3 i}}{2}$$

It might be easier to understand it as $$\exp \left(\frac{2\pi i}3 \right)^{\!2}=\exp \left(\frac{4\pi i}3 \right)$$

Comment: I often type \;  just after a square root to get a little space, to make sure that what comes after is clearly seen to be NOT under the square-root symbol......+1

Comment: ah, good suggestion.

Comment: Better `\,` than `\;`. It's a general rule I apply in my TeX code: when a variable or a parenthesis follows a radical, a thin space `\,` is most likely needed. Also `\right)^{\!2}` would push the exponent towards the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Consider equation:

$x^3-1=0$

$$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0$$

$$x^2+x+1=0$$

$$x=\frac{-1±\sqrt {1-4}}{2}=\frac{-1±\sqrt 3 i}{2}$$